# How does a failed healing spell interact with the Circle of Stars Chalice?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, healing

The Circle of Stars druid's Chalice form has the benefit:

> Whenever you cast a spell using a spell slot that restores hit points to a creature, you or another creature within 30 feet of you can regain hit points equal to 1d8 + your Wisdom modifier.

My question is whether this means "Whenever you cast a spell... *that restores hit points*" or "Whenever you cast a *spell... that restores hit points*".  That is – is it important that you cast a spell AND hit points are restored?  Or just that you cast the sort of spell that restores hit points.

This isn't an argument about the timing – it's clear the trigger is the casting of the spell from a timing standpoint.  But suppose one were to cast a Healing Word, but the spell failed for some reason – e.g. it was counterspelled.  Would the chalice benefit still occur?

Maybe counterspelling was a bad example.  What about casting a healing spell on something that can't be healed? A dead animal. A table. A player who already is at max hp.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 13):

### If it doesn't heal any damage, the benefit would not trigger

The text for chalice form specifies that it triggers when you cast a spell, using a spell slot, that restores HP. It doesn't specify that it works for spells "capable of restoring HP".

Counterspell specifically prevents a spell from working so a counterspelled spell isn't eligible anyway.

Other effects, like being under the influence of a [chill touch](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/chill-touch) spell, would also prevent it from working since you wouldn't actually be restoring any HP to the target.